# Spotify authentication with implicit grant in React not redirecting after completion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, client, spotify

I want to complete Spotify authentication using the implicit grant method in their docs. I have copied the code that seems relevant into a React component.
I managed to login to Spotify but then the page doesn't redirect back to the redirect uri.

I have added the URI to the list in the web console, but even if I do use a URI that isn't registered, it doesn't display an error. It just doesn't even try to redirect.

How can I get it to redirect after authenticating?

The component is the only thing being rendered on the page:

```
import React from "react";

const stateKey = "spotify_auth_state";

const SpotifyLogin = class extends React.Component {
  ComponentDidMount() {
    localStorage.removeItem(stateKey);
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    const client_id = "e5abbee6e0fd4e4bbd080c6d212ca520";
    const redirect_uri = "http://localhost:3000";
    const scope = "user-read-private user-read-email";
    const state = generateRandomString(16);

    localStorage.setItem(stateKey, state);

    const url = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize
                 ?response_type=token
                 &client_id=${encodeURIComponent(client_id)}
                 &scope=${encodeURIComponent(scope)}
                 &redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirect_uri)}
                 &state=${encodeURIComponent(state)}`;

    window.location = url;
  };

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Log in</button>;
  }
};

const generateRandomString = length => {
  let text = "";
  const possible =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  while (text.length <= length) {
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }

  return text;
};

export default SpotifyLogin;
```

Comment: did you put the redirect_uri in the whitelist of your spotify app?

Comment: Yes, but even using a URI that isn't whitelisted has the same effect. It doesn't even reach the invalid uri error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used a multi-line string template. This made the string have several lines and didn't concatenate the strings into one line.

Fix:

```
let url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize";
url += "?response_type=token";
url += `&client_id=${encodeURIComponent(client_id)}`;
url += `&scope=${encodeURIComponent(scope)}`;
url += `&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirect_uri)}`;
url += `&state=${encodeURIComponent(state)}`;
```